# Как при помощи bash команд распарсить xml файл с логами и найти конкретные логи по заданным параметрам?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Файл с логами содержит следующую структуру:

```
[24/11/11 09:49:57:538 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="asdfadfasas3432423ewd3da" id=23243>
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
[24/11/11 10:50:57:538 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="assasddsasd3r3r3r34r" id=dr5453>
<type>Withdrawal</type>
</Request>
[24/11/11 11:51:57:676 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="sadsdasdasdas3332ed3xew" id=frre54>
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
[24/11/11 12:52:57:345 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="sdsdfsdfldsfdsfsdfdsfsd" id=0596095>
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
```

Необходимо при помощи bash команд вытащить следующую информацию:

1. запросы и ответы в рамках сессии  asdfadfasas3432423ewd3da
2. запросы и ответы в рамках сессии  asdfadfasas3432423ewd3da и типом Balance
3. ответы с типом Withdrawal и code отличным от 0000
4. список типов операций и их количество (пример: Withdrawal: 3).

Никогда не работал с текстовыми постпроцессорами, а задачу нужно решить очень срочно.

Comment: Для этих задач `bash` не подходит. Реализовть возможно, но это очень каряво. Используйте `Python`

Answer (score 4):

### xq

Для поиска по xml подходит [xq](https://pypi.org/project/xq/). Ставится просто:

```
pip install xq
```

### Поиск

Поиск осуществляется с помощью [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). Я взял для примера `session="assasddsasd3r3r3r34r"` и **валидный** XML файл:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Requests>
<Request session="asdfadfasas3432423ewd3da" id="23243">
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
<Request session="assasddsasd3r3r3r34r" id="dr5453">
<type>Withdrawal</type>
</Request>
<Request session="sadsdasdasdas3332ed3xew" id="frre54">
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
<Request session="sdsdfsdfldsfdsfsdfdsfsd" id="0596095">
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
</Requests>
```

Команда для поиска:

```
xq '//Requests/Request[@session="assasddsasd3r3r3r34r"]' /tmp/valid.xml
```

Результат:

```
<results>
  <result>
    <Request session="assasddsasd3r3r3r34r" id="dr5453">
      <type>Withdrawal</type>
    </Request>
  </result>
</results>
```

Еще один вариант поиска:

```
xq '//Requests/Request[@session="asdfadfasas3432423ewd3da" and type="Balance"]' /tmp/valid.xml
```

Проверить валидность можно так:

```
# Установка xmllint:
sudo apt -y install libxml2-utils

# Валидация:
xmllint /tmp/valid.xml
```

### Преобразование в валидный XML

То что у вас пишется в журнал - совершенно не XML, поэтому его нужно почистить.

```
grep -vP 'DEBUG|version="1.1"' /tmp/invalid.xml | \
sed '1i <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n<Requests>' | \
sed '$a </Requests>' > /tmp/semi-valid.xml
```

Тут избавляется от строк `... DEBUG` и `<?xml ...`, затем делаем обертку и получаем полу-валидный файл.

Его не получится обработать xq, так как id написаны неверно: `id=23243` а должны быть в кавычках: `id="23243"`. Далее я просто открыл файл в текстовом редакторе и поправил эту ошибку. Получился `valid.xml`, по которому `xq` уже ищет.

Эту замену также можно сделать через `sed`, но я не стал добавлять это, скорее всего в исходном файле есть еще большая куча мусора, который придется вычистить перед обработкой.